# can I vape 40 days before ramadan?

Tags: halal-haram, sawm, ramadan

I know vaping is haram already and I shouldn't be doing it anyway but i jut want to know if it invalidates my fast if i do it in the 40 days beforehand. People keep saying that for fasts to be accepted you have to be toxin free for 40 days before Ramadan so does that include vaping? Does vaping count as intoxicating yourself as your not getting high or drunk, your in a state of knowing what you are doing. I also know that your not allowed to vape during fasts but i really just want to know the ruling outside of fasts. Please help me out by letting me know, jzk

Answer (score -2):

- I don't know about the before 40 days of fast, but just don't vape at all
- Almost all scholars will tell you that vapes are haram at all times

> Ibn 'Umar narrated that the Messenger of Allah(s.a.w) said:
> 'Indeed Allah will not gather my Ummah " - or he said: "[Muhammad's]Ummah upon deviation, and Allah's Hand is over the Jama'ah, and whoever deviates, he deviates to the Fire."
> Sunan al-Tirmidhī 2167

- Also there are over 2000 chemicals in a vape, they are extremely bad
- Vape side effects:

  - coughing
  - dry mouth and throat
  - shortness of breath
  - mouth and throat irritation
  - headaches